# NSURLConnection basic authentication issues with didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsurlconnection

Running into some weird issues with didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge. If I do something like:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WAF_URL] 
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                                   timeoutInterval:60];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
self.conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I receive - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge challenge which if successful, triggers connectionDidFinishLoading.

But, if I try to do a post with the request, I seem to be running into issue where my connectionDidFinishLoading is never triggered and my request times out.

This seems to be an issue only on iPhone and not on the simulator??!

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for a (free) HTTP request library which already implements correct handling for authentication challenges and other situations.

Comment: I am unfortunately too deep into the implementation atm to switch over. I just need to fix this one, but I will remember this for my next app; thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My server was using NTLM challenge, which when used with Post with NSURLConnection screwed up. Removed that and it's fixed.